# How can I make a scroll view scroll to the bottom?

Tags: android, listview, webview

I have tried this using methods I could find on internet.

My program is a listview containing 3000 webviews (webview inside a cardview).
(I dont think this issue is because webview being a scrollable one)

When I start the activity it is scrolled to bottom, but not the very bottom, just few webviews (around 10) out of 3000 stays below the screen.

I suspect the issue is because, the webview resizes just in milliseconds after it is *loadData* with a local String.

I have tried,

```
    mainListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            mainListView.setSelection(getCount() - 1);
        }
    });





    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

both resulting same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```

First you get the total count of the item available in your listview, the set the selection to the last item by minus 1, since the setSelection() start from 0.

Comment: Your answer would look better with more explanation.

Comment: How is this code different from @user2495720 code except that the original code is delayed to gives the listbox time to finish creation before scrolling down.